# My NSWindow's shadow is getting cut off when switching screens?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nswindow, nsvisualeffectview

I wanted to have an NSWindow with a blurred background so I created a wrapper for `NSVisualEffectView` to be used in my `ContentView()` with some help from [How do you blur the background in a SwiftUI macOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764368/how-do-you-blur-the-background-in-a-swiftui-macos-application). I also tried doing it with just the `NSWindow` using [https://github.com/lukakerr/NSWindowStyles#:~:text=true-,6.%20Vibrant%20background,A,-vibrant](https://github.com/lukakerr/NSWindowStyles#:%7E:text=true-,6.%20Vibrant%20background,A,-vibrant).

```swift
struct VisualEffectView: NSViewRepresentable
{
    let material: NSVisualEffectView.Material
    let blendingMode: NSVisualEffectView.BlendingMode
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSVisualEffectView
    {
        let visualEffectView = NSVisualEffectView()
        visualEffectView.material = material
        visualEffectView.blendingMode = blendingMode
        visualEffectView.state = NSVisualEffectView.State.active
        return visualEffectView
    }

    func updateNSView(_ visualEffectView: NSVisualEffectView, context: Context)
    {
        visualEffectView.material = material
        visualEffectView.blendingMode = blendingMode
    }
}
```

It works and looks great, however, when I move the window to a different screen -and pause with the window between both screens, then move it to the next window- it chops off a part of the `NSWindow`'s shadow.

This is what it looks like when moving screens ⤵︎

[image]

##### Is there a way to prevent this shadow chop from happening?

**Interface: SwiftUI**
**LifeCycle: Appkit AppDelegate**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out! Without any hacks too thankfully lol

[image]

## Rules

In order to achieve this look without the nasty artifacts in the question you have to do a few things the way macOS wants them.

**1. Don't set your `NSWindow.backgroundColor = .clear`!**
This is the cause for the nasty artifacts above in the first place! Leaving your window's color as is will make sure the window functions properly when changing screens. `NSVisualEffectView` captures the image behind the window and uses that for the background so there's no need to make anything transparent.

**2. Make sure to include `.titled` in the window's styleMask!**
Failure to do so will render the window without rounded corners. If you attempt to add rounded corners (like I did) to the SwiftUI view you will still have an opaque background on the `NSWindow` itself. If you then set your window's background color to `.clear` (like I did again) the shadow chop issues will ensue! However, this does not mean that the title bar will get in the way, it won't, we'll get to that in a bit.

**3. Add your `NSVisualEffectView` to your SwiftUI view!**
I found this to be easier than adding the visual effect to the `NSWindow.contentView` as a subview.

## Solution

**1. So start off by setting up your `NSWindow` and AppDelegate! ⤵︎**
All you're doing is making sure the titlebar is present but hidden.

```swift
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView()

        // Create the window and set the content view.
        // Note: You can add any styleMasks you want, just don't remove the ones below.
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200),
            styleMask: [.titled, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)

        // Hide the titlebar
        window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        window.titleVisibility = .hidden

        // Hide all Titlebar Controls
        window.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
        window.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
        window.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true

        // Set the contentView to the SwiftUI ContentView()
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)

        // Make sure the window is movable when grabbing it anywhere
        window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true

        // Saves frame position between opening / closing
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")

        // Display the window
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        window.center()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Your window will probably look something like this at this point (if starting with a blank project). You can see the 'Hello world!' isn't exactly centred due to the title bar. ⤵︎

[image]

**2. Once your `NSWindow` is setup, time to do the `ContentView()` ⤵︎**
In here you just want to create a wrapper for `NSVisualEffectView` and add it as a background. **AND THEN** make sure you remove the safe areas from the view! This makes sure to get rid of any space the title bar was eating up in the view.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(VisualEffectView(material: .popover, blendingMode: .behindWindow))

            // Very important! (You could technically just ignore the top so you do you)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

/// Takes the image directly behind the window and uses that to create a blurred material. It can technically be added anywhere but most often it's used as a backing material for sidebars and full windows.
struct VisualEffectView: NSViewRepresentable {
    let material: NSVisualEffectView.Material
    let blendingMode: NSVisualEffectView.BlendingMode

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSVisualEffectView {
        let visualEffectView = NSVisualEffectView()
        visualEffectView.material = material
        visualEffectView.blendingMode = blendingMode
        visualEffectView.state = NSVisualEffectView.State.active
        return visualEffectView
    }

    func updateNSView(_ visualEffectView: NSVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        visualEffectView.material = material
        visualEffectView.blendingMode = blendingMode
    }
}
```

At this point your view should look how you want it without any negative effects! Enjoy <3 (If you're having any problems with this solution leave a comment!)

[image]

### Resources

Thank you to @eonil for this clever way to keep the rounded corners on. Couldn't have figured this out without this answer ⤵︎
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27613308/13142325

Thank you to lukakerr for making this list of NSWindow styles!
https://github.com/lukakerr/NSWindowStyles